# Choosing reasonable indices for recovering min and max value of range as fast as possible,

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing

I have a database-table with approx. 500.000.000 rows

Version: date
UserId: numeric
Date: date

Also I have a second table where I store for each UserId the last successful calculation date.

UserId: numeric
CALCULATED_TILL: date

I want to recover for each UserId the min and max date since the last successful calculation date with respect to a specific version.

That means basically I need to get the min-max of about 1000 entries for each UserId from time to time.

There may be about 100k different Users and there are added continously new values for multiple users at once.

There may be about 10-20 different versions.

I gain very poor results with respect to performacnce, which might certainly be the result of a poor choice of indices.

I have indices soley on UserId in both tables, nothing more...

I'm not too familiar with defining indices, and I hope for someone to help me

```
Select 
min(ENTRYDATE) as MIN_ENTRYDATE, 
max(ENTRYDATE) as MAX_ENTRYDATE, 
UserId
FROM hugeTable T, lastCalulated U  
WHERE 
T.UserId  = U.UserId and 
T.ENTRYDATE > U.CALCULATED_TILL and 
AND T.VERSION = 'version-xy' 
group by T.UserId
```

I get really poor results and I need to be about 40 times faster in order to fit my purposes.

Thank you very much for any input.

Comment: please post what indexes you have when you say things are slow, query plans you get, and stats profile if possible.

Comment: You need to start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins For the question at hand can you post ddl of the two tables including indexes as well as approximate row counts for each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use `apply`

```
select u.*, ht.min_ht_date, ht.max_ht_date
from lastCalculated u cross apply
     (select min(ht.date) as min_ht_date, max(ht.date) as max_ht_date
      from hugetable ht
      where ht.user_id = u.user_id and
            ht.version = 'version-xy'
            ht.entry_date > u.calculated_till
     ) ht;
```

You want to be sure that you have an index on `hugetable(user_id, version, entry_date)`.  That index is key for any increase in performance.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you very (!!!) much for your answer, I'am still verifying, that the output of the queries are actually the same (with respeco to null value handling).

Comment: ... the performcance is actually, keanu reeves quote incoming --> breathtaking... Currently it takes about 0.5 seconds and beforehand it took about 20-30 seconds...

Comment: @user2989815 . . . You should consider accepting this (or another) answer, if you think it best solves your problem.

Comment: This answer completely solves my problem. Anyway, as mentioned in other answers, I may gain an even better performance when tweaking the indices even more, but basically your answer completely fits my needs. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

These indexes should help your query.

```
create nonclustered index ix_VER_UserId_ENTRYDATE on hugeTable (VERSION, UserId, ENTRYDATE);
create nonclustered index ix_UserId_CalculatedTill on lastCalulated (UserId, CALCULATED_TILL);
```

But ideally, you should share an actual execution plan you are getting now

Answer (score 0):

First of all be sure to have a primary key on both your tables!
This is important, an identity column will be enough.
If you have not a primary key on a table, sql server will use hash matching for it, and we do not want this.

Ok, now we can go on, I see that you need rows of only one version at a time, so this is the main filter on `hugetable`.

The best option is to build an index with all the three columns in `hugetable`,
but pay attention to the order of the columns in the index, it is very important:

`version` should be the first,
`userid` should be the second,
`entrydate` should be the third

```
create index IDX_HUGE on hugeTable (version, userid, entrydate);
```

Then you need also an index on `lastCalculated` and it should correspond to the one just described, so:

`userid` should be the first column,
`CALCULATED_TILL` should be the second

```
create index IDX_CALC on lastCalulated (userid, CALCULATED_TILL);
```

the point is to get the optimizer to apply a range filter on `hugetable` on `version` column and also to be able to use it for the join

```
Select 
    U.UserId,
    min(ENTRYDATE) as MIN_ENTRYDATE, 
    max(ENTRYDATE) as MAX_ENTRYDATE 
FROM hugeTable T
JOIN lastCalulated U ON  T.UserId  = U.UserId and T.ENTRYDATE > U.CALCULATED_TILL  
WHERE 
    T.[VERSION] = 'version-xy'
GROUP BY U.UserId
```

This is your query rewritten with `JOIN` syntax